# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'winestore'

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem where i already have created a database, but whenever I run using a php code, it keeps showing this error. Im using XAMPP, to run php and mysql.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'winestore'
>   in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpproject/search.php on line
>   4 Database Connection Failed

Here's the code

```
  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'winestore');

  if (!$connection){
      die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
  } else {
    echo "Awesome";
  }
```

Heres the picture of my mysql database

[image]

Clearly in the picture that `winestore` database has been created, I have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: Does `root` have permissions to use that database?

Comment: Try to detect error by `mysqli_connect_errno()` and what is your MySQL version??

Comment: try to set up a password then check

Comment: Technically root is the one who created the database, so yeah root have access to the `winestore` database

Comment: I think the connection establish successfully and the if condition `if (!$connection){` is wrong.

Comment: @FrayneKonok the server version is 5.6 and yeah the connection is establish successfully but it doesn't select the database